# CE Tweet Errors

Tags: twitter

I'm, getting this error in EE Debugging:

```
(0.419939 / 15.94MB)        ***  CE Tweet debug: The cache file "/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/system/expressionengine/cache/ce_tweet/p_42b4b77cc4158296d158d8647a04917e" does not exist.
(0.504468 / 16.21MB)        ***  CE Tweet debug: An exception occurred: 401 "{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}"
```

I've checked the folder has correct permissions to write the cache file to it and it has 777 on it. It creates the CE Tweet folder if it doesn't exist, but not the cache file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like CE Tweet is trying to access the cache because your OAuth credentials aren't working with Twitter. I'd double check the credentials in your config file as outlined in the [CE Tweet installation instructions](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/installation) and then try regenerating your access token for the twitter application if that doesn't work.

Comment: Doh. It looks like I'd used the Consumer Key & Consumer Secret for oAuth Token & Secret also. Don't know how I didn't spot that... It was a long night :)

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we all do it every now and then :)